# what's the choice should be done with django_wsgi and wsgi

Tags: django, wsgi, uwsgi

My current version of django is 1.6.3

And i want to deploy django on my centos server with uwsgi and nginx.

There's a  tutorial posted by someone who use 1.3's django that says it should create a file named django_wsgi.py inside my django project. I was wondering if this step could be ignored because i already have wsgi.py in my project at beginning. Are django_wsgi.py and wsgi.py the same thing? Just change the name along with the version upgrade.

```
#django.py
mport os
import sys
sys.path.append("/opt/www") 
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'your_project.settings' 
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

#wsgi.py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "netmag.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project structure generated by `startproject` changed since 1.3. Before 1.4 release, you had to manually create a `wsgi` file. [Since 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/#the-application-object), Django automatically creates `wsgi.py` file in the project root.

Continue using `wsgi.py` that Django created for you.

Comment: One more, wsgi and uwsgi, are they the same thing?

Comment: @CrayonChaney nope `wsgi` is an interface/specification, `uwsgi` is an application server container, working through the `wsgi` interface.

Answer (score 1):

A Django 1.6 already has a default WSGI configuration as you can see in your `wsgi.py` file, nothing else is needed. The instructions you mention are for legacy Django projects.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/ for more information on the Django WSGI config.